# Querying Sitecore database in code sometimes doesn't return anything

Tags: sitecore

We're using Sitecore 6.5 r111230.

We have a heavily customised Sitecore solution (delivered to us basically complete by a third-party design agency; it's largely undocumented and we no longer have any business arrangement with them) that makes extensive use of Sitecore items looked up by C# code. Ultimately the numerous layers of abstraction call `Sitecore.Data.Database.GetItem(path)` where `path` is a normal sitecore query.

Intermittently, this call returns null, against a path that is constant, referencing items I know exist and haven't changed. I have seen this happen by stepping through the code in Visual Studio.

We thought it was to do with indexing, in that periodically the sitecore logs fill up with FileNotFoundException or UnauthorisedAccessException when the index (which contains the items that are seen to be missing) gets rebuilt. However, having reviewed the documentation it seems clear that you have to explicitly query an `Index` instance to retrieve items from an index, and there is no 'magic' that redirects calls to `Database` when its content is indexed. I've therefore now ruled this out as the cause of the problem.

What might be causing this very odd behaviour?

**edit #1:**

An idea has occurred to me shortly after I posted the question. The solution includes a custom index rebuild handler, which handles the end of publish event and starts an Index Rebuild job on one of the custom indexes. If this job crashes because (for example) the account running it doesn't have the appropriate permissions on the folder where the index is stored, could that abort the publish that triggered it? This idea is supported by the observation that queries run by the 'authoring' application (which runs from `master`) seems to work fine whereas the 'delivery' application (on `web`) fails. This suggests to me a failed publish - although they're all items that should already be there prior to publishing. If that's possible, how might I verify that this is the cause?

**edit #2:**

Even more weirdly, on the same site, as far as I can tell served from the same machine (although there are two in load-balancing) different users browsing the same page get different results, where the items returned are constant and not dependent on users. I am beyond confused and am now mystified.

**edit #3:**

I may be closer to figuring out what's going on here. The items that are intermittently going missing are in a hierarchy of items that have a folder-like template, and are accessed with a path. At some time in the past, the original item was renamed as a 'backup' and a new item with the original name created, and items copied into it to preserve the hierarchy before making some incremental changes.

I think the problem is something to do with the prefetch cache, which has an entry identified by id of the **old** item (the one now renamed). I hypothesise that when the application starts up, the prefetch cache is loaded with the children of the old item, explaining either 'missing' items (ones that exist now, but weren't in the old folder when we backed it up) or 'wrong' ones (ones that were there, but have changed). When anything is published from CM or an item is saved, a higher-level cache is rebuilt with the right data, and the problem goes away, hence looking 'intermittent'.

For those of you who are experts with Sitecore: can the prefetch cache do this, if misconfigured?

Comment: Are you using standard sitecore query or fast query? Can you write an example of query which fails?

Comment: I don't think it's a fast query - those are prefixed with `fast:`, right? I'll be able to give you a concrete example tomorrow, but they're along the lines of `"sitecore/content/Reference Data/live/Whatever"`, where that path exists and always has - and this works (returns what I'd expect) almost all the time.

Comment: Any issues on the SQL Server side? You may want to check the load on the Server, make sure there is no corruption, the indexes are building correct and try running SQL Server Profiler to make sure there are no issues, as well as general network connectivity

Answer (score 2):

Here are some things that you can take a look for:

1. **Some code is switching the context database.** If the data is in Web, and the data is in Master, is there any code switching the context database over to 'Core'? The query would then not find the item because it's looking in the wrong database.
2. **Some code is switching the language.** If the data is there, but nothing's coming back, it could be there is no version in that language. Is there any code switching the context language programmatically?
3. **Data cache is corrupted** I haven't seen index rebuilding or publishes cause items that were previously there to not return on a GetItem call, but I have definitely seen cache clearing issues cause Sitecore to believe an item doesn't exist because it cleared the data but then didn't reload it into the cache again. If you do a full cache refresh (using admin\Cache.aspx) does it resolve the issue immediately?

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions - they all seem sensible. I've done some inspection of the code and I don't see any evidence of the first two. The last one though is more interesting - I'll have to wait for it to happen again to see whether this works. Interestingly, from looking at the disassembly of Sitecore.Database it **appears** that setting security on a database clears its cache by way of `CacheManager.ClearAccessResultCache()`. Of course I realise the peril of browsing the internals of someone else's framework. The code that adds the items that are going missing uses SecurityDisabler.

Answer (score 1):

A few things to rule out:

- If the API call is exactly as you describe; the issue is not Sitecore Query related. Database.GetItem() does not use Sitecore Query
- It cannot be versioning or language switching either. In both cases you would get a non-null result for your Item, even if there was no version for the context language
- It cannot be Index related either, as Database.GetItem does not utilise indexes to retrieve your results
- It cannot be related to permissions, if - as you claim - the code sits inside a SecurityDisabler()

So what are we left with?    To be honest, I think you might have a wrong assumption somewhere - that the GetItem() call returns null and therefore presumably has some other side effect. You might be seeing the side effect, and conclude it must be the GetItem call returning null. I believe this to be the case, because you say that you are getting different results on two different browsers, browsing the same box (server). In my opinion, the more likely candidates for this problem would be:

- Your scalabilitySettings.config is not enabled. This could give you problems in a multi server setup. It would however NOT account for the result you describe, where two different browsers looking at the same page on the same server, produce different results. It could, however, explain why a .GetItem() will return a result one one server, and not on another
- Caching. More specifically, per-user caching, configured on the control/component in question. This would not make your .GetItem() to return null, but it might lead you astray and make you believe it has. I would need to know more about your solution to draw up any conclusions. Per-user caching is one of the very few things in a Sitecore solution that could explain different behaviour on two separate browsing sessions on the same box
- Context Database not being what you expect. This would normally only happen if you're executing bespoke .aspx pages located outside your site root. Nothing you've written seems to indicate this being the case.

Hope this helps a bit. Would help to know more about the symptoms leading you to suspect .GetItem, or more about the solution in general.

Comment: `Database.GetItem()` takes a string that looks very much like an xpath. If that's not a sitecore query, what is it?

Comment: A path. To use Sitecore Query, you use Database.SelectItem()

Comment: I should have been explicit; I know GetItem is at fault because I've stepped through the code in the debugger and examined the result. I did examine ScalabilitySettings.config and it seems to have mostly blank fields, apparently whoever added it didn't follow the advice at the top to read the scalability guide...

Comment: I should also mention that there are two load-balanced content delivery servers, pointing at (as far as I know) the same `web` database instance. I saw different behaviour from each the other day - one seems fine; the other seems to return either nulls when I can see there are items there, or out of date items that were deleted ages ago.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with verifying database configuration references on your servers.
- connections strings point to the same databases
- database definitions are associated with correct connection strings
- site definitions use the same databases

Adding to Jay's and Maras' comments check if you have any items with dashes `'-'` or starting with `0`. If so, you'll need to add logic to wrap those with `'#'` signs. Like this: `/sitecore/content/home/#folder-name#/year/#0001#`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure we do have '-' in there - the strange thing is that this works *most* of the time. Is there a documented case where this can cause intermittent failure? It's the same items every time, by the way.

Comment: Here is an article what parts of query path you should wrap with '#' sign: http://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Using%20Sitecore%20Query/Sitecore%20Query%20Syntax.aspx